# Delphi, Creating new package and use it

Tags: delphi, package

I have created package named uik.base.v7; inside it, I have added new unit named uik.base.StringHelper.v7; like that:

```
unit uik.base.StringHelper.V7;

interface

type
  StringHelper = class
  public
    function Concat(val1: string; val2: string): string;
  end;

implementation

function Strings.Concat(val1: string; val2: string): string;
begin
  result := val1 + ' ' + val2;
end;

end.
```

Now I would like use this class from the focused project, I have just compiled the package and installed it, and finally call it, like that

```
unit OverB.Besalama.Properties.Parametres.V7;

interface

uses  
  uik.base.StringHelper.V7;
```

but the complier still raise the error saying that the unit is not found, can anyone explain how to proceed(step by step)?, I am using delphi 10.2, I need to fractionate my project.

Comment: Add the path to that unit into the **Library path** (**Tools / Options** menu, in the opened dialog **Environment Options / Delphi Options / Library** and there double click **...** and add the path to that unit). Save all, enjoy!

Comment: That should not compile. Did you mean `function StringHelper.Concat(val1, val2: string)`?

Comment: Yes, this is the most commonly missed step of installing packages which leads to this precise error - the directory where these units are located must be in Delphi's Library Path.

Comment: That's  work fine, thank you, but that mean , every dir i created, i must add to library?

Comment: @webmaster does it work when you switch to release configuration

Comment: @Nasreddine Abdelillah Galfout. Yes

Comment: @Nasreddine, of course. Modules are common for build configurations. They are separated for platforms.

Comment: @ Jerry Dodge. But, if i steel need .pas file, why dcu and bpl is for?

Comment: *.bpl is a package, *.pas is a source code and *.dcu is a compiled source code. Open source project would distribute *.pas in *.bpl. Closed source *.dcu in *.bpl. And why package ask yourself :) They are needed for visual controls registered for design time use. Runtime only package for private use (with no planned future distribution) has little practical usage.

Comment: @Victoria, I mean, if the Library is builded, why i am steel need to the source, or the .pas serve as .h in C in that situation;

Comment: In case you wish to debug the code in line with a project you're using it in. You don't *need* to keep the source in the package, but why on Earth would you want to remove it? The end result is precisely the same, whether the package consists of pas or dcu files. But your question was on a completely different topic than the difference between dcu and pas.

Comment: Yes, each directory where you have units that this package needs are to be registered in the library path. It doesn't work recursively, because there might be some directories which you don't want in the library path.